# Card Class java

Tags: java, arrays, object, arraylist

I am making a card and deck class that make a deck of 52 cards and the cardProgram class is the driver.The Card class has a property for the card's suit and a property for the value (Ace, King,10,9, etc). It also has a constructor for the properties and a toString representation for the card. The deck class ahs a property to represent cards in the deck and a constructor wit no parameters that will create 52 cards and add them to the deck, a method to randomly remove a card and return the card object that was drawn, and a toString to show the cards contained in the deck. Tha main will create the deck of cards. The user enters the number they would like to draw. Each card they draw is printed and then the cards remaining in the deck will be printed.                    I am using ArrayList to do this and I would just like to know if I am going in the right direction. I keep getting errors and I know there is something wrong in my classes. I have never used ArrayList before so any information would be appreciated

```
public class Card 
{
    private int type, value;
    private String[] cardType = {"Clubs", "Spades", "Diamonds", "Hearts"};
    private String[] cardValue = {"Ace", "King", "Queen", "Jack", "10",
                                   "9", "8", "7", "6", "5", "4", "3", "2"};

    public Card(int types, int values)
    {
        type = types; 
        value = values;
        //this.value = value;
    }

    public String toString()
    {
        String finalCard = cardValue[value] + " of " + cardType[type];

        return finalCard;
    }

}

import java.util.Random;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Deck 
{
    private ArrayList<Card> cards;

    public Deck()
    {
        for(int a =0; a<=3; a++)
        {
            for(int b =0; b<=12;b++)
            {
                cards.add(drawRandomCard());
            }
            cards.addAll(cards);
        }

    }

    public Card drawRandomCard()
    {
        Random generator = new Random();
        int index = generator.nextInt(cards.size());
        return cards.remove(index);
    }

    public String toString()
    {
        String result = "Cards remaining in deck: " + cards;

        return result;

    }    
}


import java.util.Scanner;

public class CardProgram 
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        Card C;
        Deck deck = new Deck();

        System.out.println("Enter number of cards to be dealt: ");
        int numberCards = scan.nextInt();

        System.out.println("Cards drawn: ");
        C = deck.drawRandomCard();

        System.out.println(C.toString());


    }

}
```

Comment: Well, what kind of errors?

Comment: What errors are you getting? Please be specific, and edit your question to include stacktraces/error messages

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow.com. Am I right that you have no concrete problem but only want to know if your code could be improved? When that's the case you should post this on our partner-site http://codereview.stackexchange.com instead.

Comment: I think OP is looking for Design Guidelines. Where he/she says "I am using ArrayList to do this and I would just like to know if I am going in the right direction."

Comment: `cards.addAll(cards);` Are you aware that you are adding the list of cards to itself here? (this means that you duplicate all entries in the list)

Comment: @Philipp was just looking at docs for that...am I correct that behavior will be undefined when attempting to do that, or am I misunderstanding? http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#addAll%28java.util.Collection%29

Comment: @knoight *"This implies that the behavior of this call is undefined if the specified collection is this list, and this list is nonempty.)"* Indeed. It could duplicate the list or it could also get caught in an infinite loop trying to add the last element over and over again.

Comment: @Philipp I don't think OP able to do that as `cards` instance is `null`.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at your code, I think you are getting `NullPointerException` as you are talking about `error`.

You have defined `private ArrayList<Card> cards;` but you never initialized it in your `Deck` Class.

It should go something like

```
private ArrayList<Card> cards; // currently its null
cards = new ArrayList<Card>(); // initializing here and no more null
```

Comment: I figured it out Thank you!

Comment: I am glad you figured it out. Good Luck.

Answer (score 0):

In terms of design guidelines there a couple things I would suggest:

1) Keep your local variables lower case (`Card c`)

2) Think about creating Java `Enum` for both rank and suit.
Your deck creation for loops would then look something like this:

```
cards = new ArrayList<Cards>();
for(Rank k : Rank.values())
   for(Suit s: Suit.values())
      cards.add(new Card(k,s));
```

3) An error you will get is probably an `ArrayOutOfBoundsException` since your Deck constructor is calling drawRandomCards() when initially cards is empty. Good Luck!

4) As was pointed out, you also haven't initialized cards yet.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you need. So what have I changed?

1.
When you initialised the deck, you need to populate the `ArrayList` with a card for each number combination. This is achieved by `cards.add(new Card(a,b));`. I've also removed the `cards.addAll(cards)` because you were adding the whole list to itself.

edit: oh yeh, and I initialised the ArrayList as well. That bits kind of important!

2.
In your `CardProgram`, you got the number of cards you wanted to draw, so I looped that many times calling, `drawRandomCard()`.

3.
I haven't printed the remaining cards, that's up to you to figure out.

```
public class Card 
{
private int type, value;
private String[] cardType = {"Clubs", "Spades", "Diamonds", "Hearts"};
private String[] cardValue = {"Ace", "King", "Queen", "Jack", "10",
                               "9", "8", "7", "6", "5", "4", "3", "2"};

public Card(int types, int values)
{
    type = types; 
    value = values;
    //this.value = value;
}

public String toString()
{
    String finalCard = cardValue[value] + " of " + cardType[type];

    return finalCard;
}

}

import java.util.Random;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Deck 
{
private ArrayList<Card> cards;

public Deck()
{
    cards = new ArrayList(52);
    for(int a =0; a<=3; a++)
    {
        for(int b =0; b<=12;b++)
        {
            cards.add(new Card(a,b));
        }
    }

}

public Card drawRandomCard()
{
    Random generator = new Random();
    int index = generator.nextInt(cards.size());
    return cards.remove(index);
}

public String toString()
{
    String result = "Cards remaining in deck: " + cards;

    return result;

}    
}


import java.util.Scanner;

public class CardProgram 
{
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    Card C;
    Deck deck = new Deck();

    System.out.println("Enter number of cards to be dealt: ");
    int numberCards = scan.nextInt();

    System.out.println("Cards drawn: ");
    for (int i = 0; i < numberCards; i++) {
      C = deck.drawRandomCard();
      System.out.println(C.toString());
    }

    System.out.println(C.toString());


}

}
```

Comment: I still get the error: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
 at Deck.<init>(Deck.java:19)
 at CardProgram.main(CardProgram.java:14) when i run it.    It is the lines  in Deck:   cards.add(new Card(a,b)); and in main:  Deck deck = new Deck();

Comment: @user1807844 You have never initialized `crads` instance so by default its `null` causing you `NullPointerException`. I have updated my answer, but that does not resolves another problems.

Comment: I said I'd done it, and I had in my local copy, just not pasted it back in here. have updated the code above.